# Recyclerview inside Recyclerview , get click position of child row inside parent Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my project requirement is as there are list of items are showing in Activity & i'm showing dates price with in list, what i want user will select date, the date color will change and when tap on cart item should be added to card.

**Problem :** I am not able to get child recyclerView position inside parent recyclerView `onBindViewHolder`.

Is there any way to get position of child row (dates row) inside parent reyclerview.

Below is the image , showing with three lists and in every list there are list of rows of dates. When users taps on particular date i want that date on parent recyclerView Adapter class inside onBindViewHolder.

### [image]

***Below are the adapters :***

Below is Parent Adapter Class

**FlowerListAdapter.java** :

```
public class FlowerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder>   {

    ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list;
    Context context;

    public FlowerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    //Pagination
    public void updateList(ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list) {
        this.list.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.flower_list_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getInfo().getName());
        ArrayList<CalenderPojo> listCal = new ArrayList<>();
        Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getInfo().getImage())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.imageFlower);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        holder.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //todays date
        Date cToday = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String todaysDate = df.format(cToday);
        //last day last next 90 days
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
        Date d = c.getTime();
        String lastDate = df.format(d);


        List<Date> dates = getDates(todaysDate, lastDate);
        for (Date date : dates) {

            String dayOfTheWeek = (String) DateFormat.format("EEE", date); // Thursday
            String day = (String) DateFormat.format("dd", date); // 20
            String monthString = (String) DateFormat.format("MMMM", date); // Jun
            String monthNumber = (String) DateFormat.format("MM", date); // 06
            String year = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); // 2013

            listCal.add(new CalenderPojo(dayOfTheWeek, day, "200", monthString + " " + year));
        }

        holder.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int firstVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if(firstVisiblePosition>=0)
                holder.monthName.setText(listCal.get(firstVisiblePosition+3).getMonth());
            }
        });

        holder.recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });



        //Date send to Adapter / Constructor call
        holder.adapter = new CalenderAdapter(context, listCal);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(holder.adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list.size() != 0)
            return list.size();
        else return 0;
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView imageFlower;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView monthName;
        CalenderAdapter adapter;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerNameFLR);
            imageFlower = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerImgFLR);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_calender);
            monthName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.monthName);

        }



    }


    private static List<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2) {
        ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        java.text.DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date1 = df1.parse(dateString1);
            date2 = df1.parse(dateString2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);


        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(date2);

        while (!cal1.after(cal2)) {
            dates.add(cal1.getTime());
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }
}
```

Below is Child Adapter Class

**CalenderAdapter.java**

```
public class CalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalenderAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<CalenderPojo> list;
    Context context;
    private int mSelectedItem = -1;


    public CalenderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CalenderPojo> listCal) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = listCal;
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.date_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final CalenderPojo listPotn = list.get(position);

        holder.day.setText(listPotn.getDay());
        holder.date.setText(listPotn.getDate());
        holder.price.setText("$ "+listPotn.getPrice());


        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
              // ((FlowerListAdapter)context).sendTimedetails(position);
            }
        });
        if (mSelectedItem==position) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_date_back);
            holder.day.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.price.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryLight2));
            holder.day.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            holder.date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            holder.price.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list.size() != 0 && list !=null)
            return list.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView day, date, price;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make use of interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RonakThakkar , can you answer with sample codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> Create one `interface` like this

```
public interface ClickPosition {
    public void getPosition(int position);
}
```

> Make below change in your `FlowerListAdapter.java :`

```
public class FlowerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder>   {

    ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list;
    Context context;
    ClickPosition clickPosition;

    public FlowerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    //Pagination
    public void updateList(ArrayList<FlowerListPojo> list) {
        this.list.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.flower_list_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FlowerListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getInfo().getName());
        ArrayList<CalenderPojo> listCal = new ArrayList<>();
        Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getInfo().getImage())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.imageFlower);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        holder.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //todays date
        Date cToday = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String todaysDate = df.format(cToday);
        //last day last next 90 days
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
        Date d = c.getTime();
        String lastDate = df.format(d);


        List<Date> dates = getDates(todaysDate, lastDate);
        for (Date date : dates) {

            String dayOfTheWeek = (String) DateFormat.format("EEE", date); // Thursday
            String day = (String) DateFormat.format("dd", date); // 20
            String monthString = (String) DateFormat.format("MMMM", date); // Jun
            String monthNumber = (String) DateFormat.format("MM", date); // 06
            String year = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); // 2013

            listCal.add(new CalenderPojo(dayOfTheWeek, day, "200", monthString + " " + year));
        }

        holder.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int firstVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if(firstVisiblePosition>=0)
                    holder.monthName.setText(listCal.get(firstVisiblePosition+3).getMonth());
            }
        });

        holder.recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });



        //Date send to Adapter / Constructor call
        holder.adapter = new CalenderAdapter(context, listCal,clickPosition);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(holder.adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list.size() != 0)
            return list.size();
        else return 0;
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView imageFlower;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView monthName;
        CalenderAdapter adapter;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            clickPosition= new ClickPosition() {
                @Override
                public void getPosition(int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerNameFLR);
            imageFlower = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerImgFLR);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_calender);
            monthName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.monthName);

        }



    }


    private static List<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2) {
        ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        java.text.DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date1 = df1.parse(dateString1);
            date2 = df1.parse(dateString2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);


        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(date2);

        while (!cal1.after(cal2)) {
            dates.add(cal1.getTime());
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }

}
```

> Make below change in your CalenderAdapter.java :

```
public class CalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalenderAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<CalenderPojo> list;
    Context context;
    private int mSelectedItem = -1;
    ClickPosition clickPosition;

    public CalenderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CalenderPojo> listCal, ClickPosition clickPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = listCal;
        this.clickPosition = clickPosition;
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.date_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final CalenderPojo listPotn = list.get(position);

        holder.day.setText(listPotn.getDay());
        holder.date.setText(listPotn.getDate());
        holder.price.setText("$ "+listPotn.getPrice());


        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clickPosition.getPosition(position);
                };
                // ((FlowerListAdapter)context).sendTimedetails(position);
            }
        });
        if (mSelectedItem==position) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_date_back);
            holder.day.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.price.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryLight2));
            holder.day.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            holder.date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            holder.price.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list.size() != 0 && list !=null)
            return list.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView day, date, price;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution , Thanks once again for your help @Nilesh

Answer (score 1):

Create a Recycler Touch Listner Class

```
public class RecyclerTouchListner implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListner(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Then in your parent recycler adapter, instead of setOnClicklistner use below code :

```
childRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListner(parent.getContext(), childRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListner.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

             // handle childRecycler click here

           }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create Interface:**

```
public interface RecyclerClickInterface {
void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**Create CalenderAdapter like this:**

```
holder.adapter = new CalenderAdapter(context, listCal, new RecyclerClickInterface() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
     Log.i(TAG, "position " + position);
    }
});
```

**Item click of Calender Adapter:**

```
holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mRecyclerClickInterface.onClick(view, position);
   }
});
```